# place a bitmap as background of a view

Tags: android

I have a view. I want to place a bitmap image as its background image. I was not able to do that.

```
//My code is below

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.grape);
part1 = new View(this); 
Bitmap map2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas.drawBitmap( bitmapOrg,new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()), new Rect(0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight), null);

part1.setBackgroundResource(map2); //i couldn't place map2 as bgresource to my view part1
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the API docs, [`setBackgroundResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) expects an int.

If you definitely need a bitmap, you can use [`setBackgroundDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) instead and wrap your bitmap in a [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html).

Comment: can i place a bitmap as background of a view

Comment: Just call `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grape)` directly.

Comment: But actually I need to place a bitmap there. Is there any way to do that.

Comment: as for deprecation, you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978884/bitmapdrawable-deprecated-alternative

Comment: I am trying to set a bitmap to a layout background and use that same bitmap to get x and y but my app keeps FC.