# BitmapDrawable deprecated alternative

Tags: android, drawable

I have the following code that will rotate a drawable by a set amount of degrees.

```
    public Drawable rotateDrawable(float angle, Context context)
    {
      Bitmap arrowBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.generic2rb);

      // Create blank bitmap of equal size
      Bitmap canvasBitmap = arrowBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
      canvasBitmap.eraseColor(0x00000000);

      // Create canvas
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);

      // Create rotation matrix
      Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
      rotateMatrix.setRotate(angle, canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2);

      //Draw bitmap onto canvas using matrix
      canvas.drawBitmap(arrowBitmap, rotateMatrix, null);

      return new BitmapDrawable(canvasBitmap); 
    }
```

The new SDK says that the

```
BitmapDrawable(canvasBitmap);
```

is deprecated.  Any alternatives at all?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html

Comment: Whats wrong with 'new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), canvasBitmap);'?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), canvasBitmap);
```

Comment: OK thanks, that does seem to work.  I was worried about the deprecation there!  It does seem to make the icon bigger but I will look into that further!

Comment: @LeeArmstrong It looks bigger because it is using the resource object to adjust the image to your screen's density. Often deprecating a method means that it is just no longer the right way to do things, but its often kept implemented to keep backwards-compatibility. However, Google doesn't always seem to be API friendly, so it wouldn't surprise me if they broke the old constructor in the future.

Comment: I have to create new BitmapDrawable in the static method of Tools class. I don't have access to context. How could I use this method in that case?

Comment: @Marek It seems like you have more of a code organization problem. You can have your method create a Bitmap and then create a BitmapDrawable from that in the calling method. Otherwise, you must be passing in a View or something to draw the BitmapDrawable to, in which case the Context is readily available. I cannot say more if I don't see your code, but I would create a new question if you are still confused.

Comment: Well, I have the Tools class in which I store method that rounds corners of image passed as a parameter. This class doesn't extend nothing. Here is outline of method:    public static BitmapDrawable getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels)
    {
        (...CODE HERE...)
        return bitmapDrawable;
    }

Comment: @Marek I think you should open up a new question with all the relevant source code including how you are calling that method. You may just need to refactor that method to have the context (or resources) passed into it as well.

Comment: @onit Words to live by, until it breaks, don't fix it. The first guy to say this was a genius!

Comment: This new constructor scales the bitmap, which in many cases is not the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Try this Once.

1. In Activity

   ```
   BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), blurImageBg);
   ```
2. In Fragment

   ```
   BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(getActivity(), blurImageBg);
   ```
3. In Adapter or else

   ```
   BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), blurImageBg);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin code for `BitmapDrawable`:

```
var bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(resources,bitmapObj)
```