# Quick Action PopupWindows

Tags: android

BitmapDrawable is deprecated and I'm trying to replace this code for something more current. Can someone suggest a more current code and example?

```
/**
 * On pre show
 */
protected void preShow() {
    if (mRootView == null) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("setContentView was not called with a view to display.");

    onShow();

    if (mBackground == null) 
        mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    else 
        mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackground);

        mWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mWindow.setTouchable(true);
        mWindow.setFocusable(true);
        mWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

        mWindow.setContentView(mRootView);
}
```

Comment: Is this code from you or is it an open source library ?

Comment: It is an open source Library. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978884/bitmapdrawable-deprecated-alternative) for alternative.

Comment: Its an open source library, PopupWindows from Quickaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using this library and I changed it to following and everything works fine:

```
mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Note: I tried also `mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(null)`, but it somehow kills `onTouch` listener.

Comment: Thanks! Side question, have you made any modifications for quickaction to re-size your images for you?

Comment: What exactly do you mean, but I don't think so. I just made modification to PopupWindow because if text in actionItem is very long, popup is still small and on wrong position. It was because width and height was set to WRAP_CONTENT and PopupWindow had some problems with that.

Comment: The images that go on the quick action that you supply, if they are too large and need to be re-sized...