# set background image from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

in Android, I'd like to set the background image by retrieving the image from a database. I've created the DB and put the images in as BLOB. The DB is in my assets folder and the app can access and query the DB successfully (but that may be because I'm not accessing the images yet). But now I don't know where to go from here. I imagine I have finish the code with something like:

```
bgview = (View) findViewById(R.id.bg_display);
bgview.setBackgroundResource(bgimage);
```

but I don't know how to start it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store only path of image in database not an image and you can retrieve path and set it as background .Using this you can get rid of converting into bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You might create

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(TheBytesOfTheBlobYouGotFromDB);
```

The save it to the file

try {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(FileName));

```
int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) { out.write(bytes, 0, read); }

is.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

Then set the file as a background using the solution:
[place a bitmap as background of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850395/place-a-bitmap-as-background-of-a-view)

```
Matrix Mat = new Matrix();

/// FileName is the file where you saved the 'is'
Bitmap Source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FileName);
Bitmap Destination = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( Source, DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight, true );

Source = Bitmap.createBitmap( Destination, 0, 0, Destination.getWidth(), Destination.getHeight(), Mat, true );

/// Use the 'Source' here
bgview.setBackgroundResource(Source);
```